# java regex for finding the matching string

Tags: java, regex

My string pattern is

```
"hbfj-nbsp-nbsp-wsefj-f-ejsf-sdfh-sjkf-df-sdjfk-sdfhb-jdgh-nbsp-djg-hdr"
```

I have tried this pattern `"(\\w+)-(\\w+)-(\\w+)-(\\w+)"` but it gives exact match. Required is match 0 to 3 times `"hbfj-"` these type of string.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: any match upto three hyphen

Comment: Could you show expected output/result? Is it only one result or you want to somehow split it?

Comment: For `"a-b-c"`, should it capture `"a-b-"` or the whole thing?

Comment: expected out put "hbfj-nbsp-nbsp-wsefj" , if string is hbfj-nbsp-nbsp then "hbfj-nbsp-nbsp"

Answer (score 2):

Try use this regex: `string.matches("^(\\w+(-|$)){0,3}$")`

Comment: expected out put "hbfj-nbsp-nbsp-wsefj" , if string is hbfj-nbsp-nbsp then "hbfj-nbsp-nbsp", it returns boolean expecting substring

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to extract the first hyphen separated words (up to 4):

```
String words = str.replaceAll("^(\\w+(-\\w){0,3})?.*", "$1");
```

This will return a blank if nothing suitable found.